# JavaFX-how to avoid loading null values from whatever to TextField?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

There's an input validation method contains :
some validation steps, and below line this exception only happens when edit case even empty or contains some input but works fine at save case.

```
@FXML private TextField txt_field;

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This happens when loading null to this textField and trying to get length() like:

```
txt_field.setText(null); //value is null as loaded from DB.
if(txt_field.getText().length() > 15)    //the line of exception.
```

so, what should I do when loading null values to avoid this case?.

Comment: Is an inline check like `if(txt_field.getText()!=null && txt_field.getText().length() > 15)` too messy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you cannot check the database coming out of the database for nullness, you could do something like

```
var myText = txt_field.getText();
if(myText != null && myText.length > 15) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the text to something not null directly, you could try:

```
txt_field.setText(dbValue == null? "" : dbValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with java-8, you might try using Optionals:

```
Optional dbValue = Optional.ofNullable(getDBValue());   // get the value from the DB
txt_field.setText(dbValue.orElse("");
```